# mysql querying information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES for full text support

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below code to query if mysql supports full text searching for innodb.

I am just wondering if there are any permissions that can can cause information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES to not be available?

Is there a better way to find out if the database supports full text? I have tried this on a couple shared servers. I am just wondering if there are any odd setups where this won't work or cause a fatal query error.

```
function supports_full_text()
{
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'innodb_ft_cache_size'");

    return $result->row()->count > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Full-text searches are supported for InnoDB and MyISAM tables only. FULLTEXT index support for [InnoDB tables requires MySQL 5.6.4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html) or higher.

[5.6> supports fulltext](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) search for InnoDB.  One of the big pushes to 5.6 was so that tables that were MyISAM in prior versions 5.5< could be converted to InnoDB in order to completely move away from MyISAM.

Comment: I understand what is supported; please read question more carefully. I am trying to programmatically determine if they have full text available in their database. My users will have different versions of mysql.

Comment: My application is downloaded and end users deploy it to their servers. I just want to make it as compatible as possible. They might also use one of the MySQL forks.

Comment: Yeah once again...just check version...MySQL forks have their equivalent to vanilla...